# Unify name of the months with each date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my table "months", which is composed by an "id", and the column "dateMonth" for example '2012-03-01', with all the months of a lot of years (well and now id of table "nameMonths").

My other table "nameMonths" which has an id and every month name.

What I'm trying to achieve is to insert the "nameMonths" id, on each "months" column depending on what month it is, for example if the register of "months" is '2012-06-01', insert the id that belongs to June.

What I have now: table "months"

```
id = 1(AI) dateMonth = 2013-02-01 idNameMonth = NULL (here I want the id of table "nameMonth")
```

What I have now: table "nameMonth"

```
idNameMonth = rx34 (for example) value = "June"
```

What I want: table "months"

```
id = 1 dateMonth = 2012-06-01 idNameMonth = rx34 (relating to June).
```

Is there any way to do it guys? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a separate table for month names when MySQL has this functionality built-in?  Sample data and desired results would help if you want this implementation.  It is not clear how the table are connected.

Comment: can you just give us a little example maybe on fiddle, and give us the expected results?

Comment: Because they were already made

Comment: Trying to relate the month of "dateMonth", with the id of "nameMonths", i don't know if that's posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the mysql date function

```
select month('2012-06-01 '), monthname('2012-06-01 ')
```

or based on youf table

```
select m1.month(dateMonth), m2.name
from months m1
inner join nameMonths m2 on 1.month(dateMonth) = m2.id
```

or based on new sample

```
update months 
inner join nameMonth ON lower(nameMonth.value)= lower(monthname(months.dateMonth))

set months.idNameMonth  = nameMonth.idNameMonth
```